# Check out github repository in ADO pipeline [YAML]

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, yaml, repository

I have a github repository: https://github.com/user-name/repo-name

I'm following this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#faq to checkout multiple repositories. Here is my yaml file:

```
name: 1.0

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyGitHubRepo
    type: github
    endpoint: https://github.com/user-name/repo-name
    name: repo-name
    ref: master

trigger:
- master
- develop
- features/*

pool:
  vmImage: "vs2017-win2016"

variables:
  "BuildConfiguration": 'debug'
  "BuildPlatform": 'any cpu'

stages:

- checkout: MyGitHubRepo
- template: build.yml@MyGitHubRepo
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi, thank you for checking in. Question - The yaml file in my example is located in an ADO repo and I need to checkout a GitHub repo. I'm still confused on the service connection part.

Comment: Hi, I have shared the detailed steps in my answer, please check it and kindly share the result here.

Comment: Hi, I recommend that you create a new ticket, then share the yaml build definition, GitHub yml file and error log. We need check it and help you. Thanks.

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT Could you please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64867728/refer-to-the-external-code-in-github-repo-from-ado-repo/64873087#64873087

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is in the `repositories.endpoint` setting. The `endpoint` setting should reference an Azure Devops Project `Service connection`. A project service connection is a reference to a service or resource at the project level in Azure DevOps that allows you to store credentials etc for referencing resources and services safely without the need for storing credentials for those resources in your code. Specific Azure pipeline tasks and  `azure-pipelines.yaml` properties can easily reference the service connections.

To set up a service connection, click `Project settings` at the bottom of the page in the browser while in your Azure DevOps project. Then in the left menu under `Pipelines` click `Service connections`. At the top right of the page click `New service connection` and choose `GitHub` and click `Next`

On the next page, select `Grant authorization` if it is not already selected. Choose `AzurePipelines` for the OAuth Configuration and click `Authorize`. Confirm the GitHub pop-up and enter your GitHub credentials to do so. Next click `Authorize Azure pipelines` on the GitHUb authorization dialog. Then back on the Azure DevOps page take note of the service connection name for reference later on and click `Save` to finish creating the service connection.

Then back to your `azure-pipelines.yaml` edit as below:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyGitHubRepo
    type: github
    endpoint: name_of_service_connection_you_created
    name: github-user-name/repo-name
    ref: master
```

Make sure to set the `type` to GitHub and take care to set the `name` value to the combination of your GitHub user name and repository name like `username/reponame`.

Reference for the repository resource in `azure-pipelines.yaml` can be found in the [YAML schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#repository-resource)

Documentation for creating can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Comment: Thank you! Does that mean I can checkout only repositories in Azure DevOps using type as Git? Can I not checkout a repository in GitHub?

Comment: You can checkout GitHub as shown in the example by setting the `type: github` and creating the service connection to GitHub

Comment: thank you! How do I create service connection to GitHub?

Comment: I explain the creation of a github service connection in paragraph 2 and 3 of my answer. More detailed information on creating any service connection can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#create-a-service-connection) and more specific information on the GitHub specifics on such a service connection can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-github)

Comment: What if you are only going to use a github repo as an external resource (read-only), do you really need to setup a service connection for that? Then it seem almost simpler to just run "git clone" in a script/pwsh step?

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

Login [GitHub Token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) page and create PAT Token.

Open project settings->Service connections->Click the button `New service connection` and select GitHub type to create GitHub connection.

[image]

The sample I shared is publish GitHub repo as Artifacts.

GitHub repo.

[image]

YAML sample:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: vitol
    type: github
    endpoint: GithubTest
    name:  vitoliutest/vitol

trigger:
  - none
pool:
  name: Hosted Ubuntu 1604
steps:
  - checkout: vitol
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)'
      Contents: '**'
      TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
      ArtifactName: 'drop'
      publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Note: Please notice the step `checkout`, it is used to checkout GitHub repo.

Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was able to checkout a repository in my GitHub after adding service connection. Do I have to be the owner of the GitHub repository to checkout?

Comment: Hi @user989988, you should be GitHub repo contributor, then It could checkout the repo.