# Refer to the external code in GitHub repo from ADO repo

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, yaml, repository

I have 2 repositories - 1 ADO & 1 GitHub:

ADO repo contains internal code

GitHub repo contains external code

I'm using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops to checkout the above repositories.

I need to use some code files in GitHub repo to build the code in ADO repo (meaning internal code in ADO repo has dependency to external code GitHub repo).

**Example**

```
<ADO repo>

<ADO-code-file>

<content>:

private readonly IXYZ _log = null;

<GitHub repo>

<GitHub-code-file>: IXYZ.cs

<content>:

public interface IXYZ
{
}
```

build for internal code in ADO repo

```
private readonly IXYZ _log = null;
```

is failing now because IXYZ.cs is a part of GitHub repository.

Is it possible to refer to the external code in GitHub repo from ADO repo?

Comment: You're probably going to want a submodule here.

Answer (score 0):

It's able to refer a public repo (GitHub) as submodule in Azure DevOps Git Repo.

> Select if you want to download files from submodules. You can either
> choose to get the immediate submodules or all submodules nested to any
> depth of recursion. If you want to use LFS with submodules, be sure to
> see the note about using LFS with submodules.
>
> The build pipeline will check out your Git submodules as long as they
> are:
>
> - Unauthenticated: A public, unauthenticated repo with no credentials    required to clone or fetch.
> - Authenticated:
>   Contained in the same project, GitHub organization, or Bitbucket    Cloud account as the Git repo specified above.

Added by using a URL relative to the main repository. For example, this one would be checked out: `git submodule add /../../submodule.git mymodule` This one would not be checked out: `git submodule add https://dev.azure.com/fabrikamfiber/_git/ConsoleApp mymodule`

A sample for your reference:

```
[submodule "DBPkg"]
  path = DBPkg
  url = ../DBPkg
```

You could also check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34618962/5391065

Comment: Thank you! How does adding git submodule fix the above issue I'm having?

Comment: @user989988 `is failing now because ILoggingRepository.cs is a part of GitHub repository.`  Instead of downloading/checking out two repos separately through script/api in Azure DevOPs pipeline. if you switch to use submodule, this error across different repos  should not happen again. Suggest you give a try locally first.

Comment: Hi  @user989988, any update on this, have you figured out it？